# My dotnet build fails when I try to build it using command line

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-6.0

I am using Visual Studio and have .NET 6 installed.

The application builds from Visual Studio. I am trying to build my application from the command line and getting this error when I run `dotnet build`:

> C:\code\Outlook\MyProject\MyProject.csproj(1217,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.418\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v17.0\WebApplications
> \Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.418\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v17.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

I can see the file does not exit on the disk but why is the command trying to access the file. And what would be the correct way to fix the build

Comment: Because of `MyProject.csproj(1217,3)`, 1217 is the line number.

Comment: A csproj with >1200 lines? Wow ...

Comment: It's possible that the cmdline is [using the wrong msbuild](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/msbuild-started-throwing-error-msb4019-out-of-the/1617167).

Comment: @Fildor, if I remember correctly, msbuild actually imports/merges a bunch of `.target` files into the project during the build process. I have a feeling line 1200 may not actually have come from the csproj itself. Then again, if this was an [old format csproj](https://natemcmaster.com/blog/2017/03/09/vs2015-to-vs2017-upgrade/), 1200 is not out of the question.

Comment: @NPras Not impossible. I'd be surprised nonetheless.

Comment: This is because when the project was run before, the previously configured library file path would be saved in the corresponding .csproj file. When you run the project again, the previous library file path will also be searched, but the corresponding library file path cannot be found at this time. library file (because we have moved it), so an error will be reported. Use Notepad++, open the .csproj project file corresponding to the project name, find your previous path in it, delete that statement, save the changes and reopen the project to run normally.